# [SQL Server]Implicit conversion from data type nvarchar(max) to varbinary(max) is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query

Tags: sql-server, laravel, varbinarymax

That is my code

```
DB::statement(DB::raw('EXECUTE dbo.SP_WS_CUST_MAIN ?,?,?,?,?,?,?'),
    [ $USER_ID, $CUST_PYMT_MTHD, $CUST_CMMNT, $CUST_NAME, $ANDROID_LOCATION,
      DB::raw("CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), $value)") , $WEEKDAY]
);
```

How can convert nvarchar(max) to varbinary(max)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of three possibilities. The simplest would be to create a shell stored procedure (say `dbo.SP_WS_CUST_MAIN_VC`) that simply accepts the parameters, including `$value` as a varchar(max), then does the conversion of `$value` to a `varbinary(max)` and calls the target stored procedure. This ensures proper quoting with the parameter replacement.

The second (and most hazardous) is to embed the `CONVERT` into the parameters directly, opening yourself to all sorts of SQL Injection ugliness.

The third would be to create a UDF that accepts a `varchar(max)` and returns a `varbinary(max)`, and embed that into the base `EXECUTE` call, e.g.:

```
DB::statement(DB::raw('EXECUTE dbo.SP_WS_CUST_MAIN ?,?,?,?,?,dbo.castAsVarbinary(?),?'),
    [ $USER_ID, $CUST_PYMT_MTHD, $CUST_CMMNT, $CUST_NAME, $ANDROID_LOCATION,
      DB::raw("CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), $value)") , $WEEKDAY]
);
```

Any of these would work, but (1) and (3) should also be secure.